# Pass slash as a parameter on url in applicationg setting

Tags: extjs, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an extjs application that sends a parameter to an application setting with a slash... for eg "Tiger/Cheetah", to print a report... my ssrs report also takes that parameter fine... but when going through a web browser the passed parameter does not take "Tiger/Cheetah" with the slash... it takes "Tiger" but there are no records for that in the report...

I tried to replace / with %2f like this

```
Tiger%2fCheetah
```

and it's not working...

is there any other way?

Comment: I think encoding the slash is an appropriate way to go; in what way is that not working?

Comment: Thans Mike... well.. in my browser's address I can see the passed parameter is 'Tiger/Cheetah' when encoding... but on my console.log it shows 'Tiger%2fCheetah'... so when my application is trying to feed this to my ssrs reports, it does nothing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this is easy

```
encodeURIComponent('Tiger/Cheetah')
```

and the other side must do vice verse

```
decodeURIComponent('Tiger%2fCheetah')
```

Comment: what do you mean by other side sra... coz my application setting just takes the url and passes the parameter to ssrs reports

Comment: do you mean there is a settings on bids that will decode the %2f to /

Comment: @EagleFox Well, first I must say that I've totally overseen that fact. You should definitively edit your question and add the `SSRS` Tag *Btw. tags like slash, settings or url are most ime quite useless* It's a bit hard for me to follow up where exactly your problem is. Is it with the generated report? Cause You said that the report handles all fine...

Comment: the report runs fine with single word parameters... parameters with "/" doesn't get the report... so my problem is trying to pass that parameter... it never gets to my reports

Comment: @EagleFox I guess you are using **[URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx)** and based on this it should work. I seems to depend somehow on the serverside. I will fix your tags so that some SSRS geeks may get this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the slash with another slash?  Try passing

```
Tiger//Cheetah
```

If you were using BIDS (VB), you could call REPLACE() to do this for you.  I use this when passing parameter containing slashes or backslashes.

```
REPLACE(VariableName,"/","/")
```

Answer (score 0):

try replace(Fields!SomeName.Value,"\","\"). It worked when i have record set having black slash value to be passed to a javascript URL

Peter J